# Where to ask a theoretical computer networking question?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, site-recommendation

I have a theoretical computer networking question about IPv4. It clearly does not belong to Stack Overflow, but the problem is that we do not have a dedicated computer networking site and I am confused which one of these sites (all have computer networking questions and tags) might be a better place.

I posted here :

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297331/why-did-he-assume-1024-1000)(closed)
- [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23639/why-did-he-assume-1024-1000)(closed)
- [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/990668/why-did-he-assume-1024-1000)(removed)
- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/731105/why-did-he-assume-1024-1000) (removed)

and [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags) does not have tags for IPv4.

---

I have not any tutor. My source of leaning is only Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange.

> Where do I ask a theoretical computer networking question?

Some people had tried to support my question and they had reopened my question for one hour , and after all  , my question again on put on hold by moderator Stack Overflow == I feel like , this is my fault (I did more work. Tired ,depressed) :(

Comment: I just asked a [question](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1136/would-this-theoretical-networking-question-be-on-topic-here) about this on Meta Computer Science. I'll post an answer here as soon as I get some feedback from the CS users.

Comment: But I have not posted there(http://cs.stackexchange.com/) , since no tags for the IPv4, rt ?

Comment: You haven't. I asked on their **meta** site if it would be a question that could be asked there.

Comment: Ok , thank in advance .

Comment: Also, it's pretty quiet over there, so it may take a day or three to get an answer.

Comment: I'd consider that a rant about a silly exam question, not as a real question.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the question on Super User was closed for being _unclear_ **not** for being off topic. Though I'm still not sure this falls under the umbrella of "personal and home computer networking".

Comment: @HPierce - One of the SU mods commented: [Between 'offtopic' and 'unclear what you're asking' I picked the latter, but even if your question was worded differently, I'd suspect this would still be closed](http://superuser.com/questions/990668/why-did-he-assume-1024-1000#comment1365756_990668)

Comment: I see it as a simple exam question about bit calculation in a data structure: start with 50 bits - IPv4 address (check if student knows it is 32 bits) - sub-second counter (must be able to store at least 1000) = how many bits are left for storing the seconds, so what is the period of the unique id

Comment: Network Engineering is off topic because the only network-related bit is knowing that IPv4 addresses are 32 bits. Super User and Server Fault also are off-topic because the question has nothing to do with using computers or running servers etc.

Comment: So I think it comes down to deciding whether exam questions about data structures and counting bits are on-topic on Stack Overflow....

Comment: @SanderSteffann The problem is more aournd the wording of the question than the subject itself, Barry's answer explain it better than me. For my part sounds on topic around binary understanding for network programming at least.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I think the only relationship of the question to IPv4 is that IPv4 addresses are used. I do not know of any IPv4 header which uses that structure (but possible some routing protocols may do). So IPv4 is simply the wrong context, thus the rejections. It is like asking a question about accounting on maths SE and claiming it is in-place because it is about numbers.

Comment: I've updated my [question](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1136/would-this-theoretical-networking-question-be-on-topic-here) on Meta CS now that this is re-opened here. I'm still going to try to get some feedback there about what kinds of networking questions we should send to them.

Comment: @syck I presume it's more a kind of session table implementation than routing in itself. But yes IPV4 is just an input data for the problem and not the subject on itself.

Comment: So , finally , I can't ask that question anywhere .

Comment: As an aside: it is **not** true that *any* question can be asked on some site from the SE network. There are questions that are off-topic on all sites. Such question either shouldn't be asked (on SE. You may find other places different from SE where the question is fine), or you should open a proposal for a site where it would be on topic. The fact that a question isn't on topic on any site doesn't mean you can simply ask it on the most similar site use that as an excuse for make it accepted. More generically: don't circumvent the rules.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd say this is on-topic on SO. It's basically a question about designing a data structure, which would be a specific programming problem - even if it isn't literally about writing code.

However, you definitely need to reword the question so as not to be so whiny. This:

> Note that if I assume 1024 = 1000 (**but this is not fair**), then answer is is 256.

is ridiculous. When I saw your question, I wanted to close it on the basis of not wanting to seek out an answer. The answer does not come from assuming that two unequal numbers are equal, and said assumption would have nothing to do with "fairness" anyway.

If you worded your question to simply emphasize that your understanding was that you had 18-bits left over, and thus the period should repeat every 2<sup>18</sup>/1000 ~ 262 seconds, and simply stated that the answer was 256 instead of trying to divine malicious intent from the grader, then I think your question would be better received.

As a hint, the answer does not require that 1000 == 1024. Simply that 1024 happens to be the smallest power of 2 that is larger than 1000.

Comment: sir , I'm sorry , but my intention was showing that how  given key may false . Correct me , if I'm wrong ?

Comment: @Silence You know you're wrong because your answer (262) isn't the correct answer (256). In trying to show why you think the actual answer is wrong, instead of trying to provide any kind of technical explanation, you're going with "it's not fair." If you don't understand the answer, it's perfectly ok to ask *why* 256 is the answer. But you're effectively just calling the grader a jerk, which isn't helping anybody.

Comment: Don't ask people to prove that the question wasn't fair (a.k.a. whining) and ask about how to construct a unique id from the data. You'll see whether the question was wrong or you are wrong from the answers. I agree that SO is not the place to complain about exam questions. Try to learn, not to criticize

Comment: So , finally , I can't ask that question anywhere .

Comment: @GeorgeStocker How was this a "general software" question? It's a specific data structure question.

Comment: *" It's basically a question about designing a data structure, which would be a specific programming problem"* - Actually I disagree, *designing a data structure* is more of a computer science problem, it's not a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 14):

This morning I asked a [question](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1136/would-this-theoretical-networking-question-be-on-topic-here/1137) on your behalf over at the Computer Science (CS) Meta. But, before continuing on to the answer, it's time for a little tough love<sup>1</sup>.

One thing that the moderator at CS ([D.W.♦](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/users/755/d-w)) pointed out, and that I'd like to emphasize here:  Cross posting<sup>2</sup> questions to multiple sites in the network is very much frowned upon. Doing so in quick succession is especially troublesome. It's rude to the users at each of the sites, not to give them each the best attempt at a question that you can muster. Please use some care in the future with *how* you go about it. If a question is closed at one site rather than being migrated, use that as an opportunity to re-evaluate the question and how it's being asked. Fix typos, grammar, formatting, and title before asking the new question.

Also, not every site in the Stack Exchange (SE) network is as ridiculously highly trafficked as Stack Overflow (SO) and Meta Stack Overflow (MSO). Sometimes an answer may take hours or even days to come. This network is not an instant answer factory, nor should it be.

---

Now that the meta part is out of the way, let's look at the question, using the [answer](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1137/41436) from the CS Meta Question. Anyone interested only in the general case recommendations can feel free to skip this part.

The question as written is not a good fit for CS for several reasons.

1. The question is broadly about why a certain answer is being shown as correct in the answer key. Unless the person who wrote that answer is available, no one will be able to give you an authoritative answer. Or as D.W. puts it:

   > If you want to know why the answer-key-author thought 256 was the correct answer, then you need to ask them.
2. Questions asking, "is my answer correct?" are problematic. Quoting from [this answer](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/641/41436)<sup>3</sup>:

   > If the attempt is wrong, good answers can be given, pointing out the mistake and proposing (hints for) fixes, [but] if the attempt is correct, nothing can be said but "yes, it's correct".

   Another issue with this type of question is that they are rarely useful to future users. Consider the question "Does 2+2=4?" The only correct answer is "Yes." Only someone looking for confirmation that they added 2 and 2 correctly will ever find that question useful.<sup>4</sup> Proof/provability questions are similarly difficult to answer in a way which is useful to others. (See [Questions about correctness of a solution](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/questions-about-correctness-of-a-solution))
3. Taken at the most basic level the question is about the arithmetic, which is not really on-topic anywhere. (Not even on the mathematics-specific sites.)

Now time for the good news, if ***and only if*** you can reword your question to be more conceptual, then it would probably be acceptable. D.W. gives a couple good options, and you really should read the entire answer and spend some time considering it. For the sake of completeness, I'll share one of his possibilities.

> I want to generate a global unique ID based on my IP address and a counter, and I'd like to maximize the time for a particular host's ID to wrap around. I am promised that my IP address will be unique. I have only 50 bits for my unique ID. How should I do this, to maximize the time until wrap-around? What's the optimal design, and what will the wrap-around time be?

Asking this way won't necessarily give you a direct answer to your original question, but, even better, it will give you the tools you need to solve similar problems for yourself in the future.

---

For the general case when deciding whether to post on CS: (Or when recommending CS to someone)

1. As always use the [help center](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as a first line of defense against off-topic.
2. Practical and theoretical networking questions are welcome on CS. (Provided they fit within all of the other quality guidelines.)
3. Conceptual questions are better than implementation questions. Don't ask a question like "How would I do X in python?" which will be read as "someone write this code for me, so I can go to the bar" regardless of how you mean it.
4. You should, to take D.W. slightly out of context,

   > diagnose gaps in [your] understanding, and then use that to help [you] write a question about the concept [you] are uncertain about.
5. If referring, as always, use your best judgement. Referring someone's question to a site where it will be quickly closed as off topic is unfair to the user, wastes everyone's time, and makes more noise here at meta for us to deal with. (The inevitable: "You guys are jerks, why did you tell me to ask on X if it's not allowed there?" followed by defacement, spiteful serial downvoting, ragequitting, and blog posts about how stupid everyone on SO is these days.)

---

*<sup>1</sup> Tough love: an expression used when someone treats another person harshly or sternly with the intent to help them in the long run. [[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tough_love)]*

*<sup>2</sup> Cross posting: The copying of a post in part, or in whole to multiple sites. See also: [Crossposting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossposting) at Wikipedia<sup>†</sup>*

*<sup>3</sup> The answer is written by another moderator at CS, [Raphael♦](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/users/98/raphael). It is definitely worth a read, and will help you when deciding how to phrase questions anywhere.*

*<sup>4</sup> The former close reason "Too Localized" was designed to fit this case.*

*<sup>5</sup> Note: algorithm, not program*

---

***Disclaimer: These are my words, not those of D.W., Raphael or anyone else, except where quoted. While the answer I gave here is based in large part on the advice given to me at Computer Science, the opinions expressed, and the way they are expressed are solely my own. Furthermore, I am not an active user of CS, and I don't know all of their quality standards and possible edge cases.***

---

<sub>*Can't believe I managed to keep this under <del>500</del> <del>800</del> <del>1000</del> 1500 words.*</sub>

<sub>*† What did we do before we could link to Wikipedia for everything? And before you ask, yes, this is a footnote in a footnote. :)*</sub>